# PhD interview question: BSc dissertation/'thesis'

Tags: phd, thesis, mathematics, interview, physics

My BSc dissertation was basically a literature review of Sean Carroll lecture notes on general relativity.

I got a first in this, and was offered PhD interviews with the supervisors being aware of this so it must suffice. I'm unsure how you explain the motives and conclusion of such a piece of work. By doing a literature review I have pretty much, almost, produced my own set of lecture notes.

This is a common question in interviews that throws me.

Any advice?

Comment: "a literature review of sean caroll lecture notes" What do you mean by this? A literature review is usually a survey of the literature; restricting it to a specific individual seems odd, to (presumably) unpublished literature (lecture notes) even more so.

Comment: Well, how did you explain the motivation and conclusions in the dissertation itself?

Comment: erm I thought on something like this for the intro/motive:
General covariance motivated Einstein to genereralise special relativity (the principle only holding in inertial frames to relative accelerated frames)Unexplained precession of perihelion of Mercury by Newtonian formulation and this for the conclusion: cosmological constant problem, the cosmological constant not naturally arising-other means to explain universe accelerating? the coincidence problem, all motivate modified theories of gravity . (have touched on how I will continue the concluding leads of this project to my next project)